# One to one functions, onto functions, and divisibility

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f$ be the function from $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$, defined by $f(x,y) = 2x+4y$

Let $g$ be the function from $\mathbb Z \to \{0,1,2,3\}$, defined by $g(a) = a \pmod 4$.

1. Is $f$ one-to-one? I think the answer is no because $f(-2,1) = f(0,0)$, but $(-2,1) \ne (0,0)$.
2. Is $f$ onto? I think the answer is no because $2x+4y$ is and even integer so $f$ will never hit any odd integer.
3. Is $g(f(x,y))$ one-to-one? I'm not sure about this one. the composite will be $2x+4b \pmod 4$. That means an even number divided by $4$ right? But how can I use that in my proof?
4. Is $g(f(x,y))$ onto? I'm not sure how to do this one either.

Comment: It seems as though $f$  is a function from $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. That is, $f$ takes an ordered pair of integers $(x, y)$ and sends it to an element in $\mathbb Z$

Comment: For everything past the first four questions consider asking a new question since now it's kinda cluttered, and for 3 can you find two odered pairs which have the same modulo 4?

Comment: yes!  (1,1) and (3,0) so it is not one to one! Thanks!

Comment: Can you help me with the rest:) ?

Comment: So you're a girl.  Stand up and show what girls can do! Change your username to "more than just a girl."

Answer (score 0):

For 3, any function with finite range and infinite domain cannot be one-to-one.  Your example from 1 will work for this as well, but there are others like $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ where the values of $f(x,y)$ disagree, but the values of $g(f(x,y))$ agree.
For 4, your insight in 2 applies.  Since $f(x,y)$ is always even $g(f(x,y))$ can only be $0$ or $2$.

Comment: Thanks! do you know how can I prove that and even number mod 4 must be 0 or 2?

Comment: An even number is of the form $2k$.  Then $k$ is either even or odd....